# Why does ef core populate related data of a list of entities but not doing so for single entity

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have two repo method, one is retrieving single entity while the other one is retrieving a list of entities.

```
public async Task<Model> GetAsync() 
{
    return await _dbContext.Models.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s....);
}

public async Task<IList<Model>> GetListAsync()
{
    var list = await _dbContext.Models.Select(s => .....).ToListAsync();
}
```

Based on the documentation of EF Core, related data will be loaded in Model object if `Include()` is called and vice versa. However, when I'm retrieving a list of entities and the related data get loaded regardless `Include()` is called. Is it by design?

Comment: At first examine SQL. But I think related data is already in ChangeTracker and binded automatically.

Comment: From your code, there is no `Include`, `Include` can automatically recognize foreign keys for related queries.